# View not rendering MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view which is not being called when I step through the code I see it get to the action in the controller and return the view but it does not load the view it just stays on the current page.

When a button is clicked on a specific page an ajax post is made calling the next page this does not load.

My contoller action looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Comparison(int[] y)
        {
            CostModel.Getsuff(y);        

            return View(CostModel);
        }
```

My route map looks like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Compare",
        url: "Category/Comparison/{*xxxx}",
        defaults: new { Controller = "Category", Action = "Comparison" }
       ).RouteHandler 

= new CategoriesRouteHandler(); 



public class CategoriesRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
        {
            public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
            {
                IRouteHandler handler = new MvcRouteHandler();
                var vals = requestContext.RouteData.Values;
                var list = vals["xxxx"].ToString().Split(',');
                int[] y= new int[list.Length];
                for (int i=0; i < list.Length; i++)
                  int.TryParse(list[i].ToString(),out y[i]);

                vals.Add("y", y);
                return handler.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
            }
        }
```

My ajax

```
  $.ajax({ 
       type: "POST", 
      url: '@Url.Action("Comparison", "Category",  new { Categories = "PLACEHOLDER"})'.replace('PLACEHOLDER', arr),
       dataType: "json", 
       traditional: true, 
       success: function(msg){alert(msg)} 
    } );
```

As I mentioned previously when I trace it, it performs the ajax call fine and hits the action on the controller it just does not launch the view. I thought it may have something to do with the fact that the area is not defined anywhere? So perhaps its throwing it out, can't see anywhere in MVC 4 to specify different area, but I am new to MVC. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As I mentioned previously when I trace it, it performs the ajax call
>   fine and hits the action on the controller it just does not launch the
>   view.

That's the whole point of AJAX => stay on the same page. If you want to replace the current page don't use any AJAX. Use a normal `Html.ActionLink`.

And if your controller action only returns a `PartialView` and you would like to refresh only a portion of your page, you could do that in the `success` callback:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: '@Url.Action("Comparison", "Category",  new { Categories = "PLACEHOLDER"})'.replace('PLACEHOLDER', arr),
    traditional: true, 
    success: function(result) {
        $('#someIdToRefresh').html(result);
    } 
});
```

Also notice that I have removed `dataType: 'json'` because your controller action is not returning any JSON. It's returning `text/html`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response as you may have guessed I am new to ajax too, much appreciated made my weekend :)

Answer (score 1):

From your action method, you are returning HTML (the rendered view), while your Ajax call expects JSON as the response's format.

I believe an exception is being thrown when the response arrives.