# Rendering an html string to view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two controller actions that target the same view.  That is, I have specified a view name on the call to View from controller action.  The second action puts an html string in a ViewBag. I simply just want to display this html string in the view.  I have tried

```
@ViewBag.HtmlDoc
```

and

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.HtmlDoc)
```

but nothing is rendered.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

--controller code---

```
public ActionResult ShowReport(string URL)
        {
            string tableString = ""; 

            [Code to Create table called ReportTable and add rows etc]

            tableString = RenderControlToString(ReportTable );

            ViewBag.Table= tableString; 

            return View("ShowReport");

        }
```

I debugged the ViewBag.Table on the View and can see the html string.  But the View never gets updated / rendered.  I tested with a simple text like:

```
@if (ViewBag.Table != null)
{
        //@ViewBag.Table;       
        @:The day is: @DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.
}
```

It goes into the code so I know ViewBag.Table  is not null, but the string doesn't get rendered, either.

Do I need to refresh RenderBody() in the _layout.cshtml??? or something to that effect?

-- ajax call--

a button onclick event calls this ajax method:

```
$.ajax({

            url: "/Home/ShowReport",
            data:  { URL: urlString} ,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data) {
               alert(data);
            },
            error: function (e, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert(e.statusText);

            }

        });
```

Comment: you absolutely have to include code samples. not easy to include enough code and not make it overwhelming, but otherwise your scenario is not follow-able

Comment: Thanks, I've shortened my explanation since it was too wordy.

Comment: That's odd. You don't need Html.Raw for this. your first attempt should do it every time. add the controller code where you populate you ViewBag variable. I cant think of any other issue than it failed to populate.

Comment: probably its populated with nothing

Comment: have you confirmed that `tableString` gets populated? with debugger?

Comment: I'm also confused cause i dont see you rendering ViewBag.Table, just using it for logic... the variable you do render I dont see populated...

Comment: Yes, with debugger I can confirm it is populated.  The example above, where I have commented out //@ViewBag.Table, is where I woult have rendered it.  I just commented it out so I can show that I can't even render a simple string ( @:The day is: @DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek)

Comment: ok, IC, this is html. yes, you will need to use `Html.Raw(ViewBag.Table)`

Comment: Yes, I had tried Html.Raw(ViewBag.Table) and nothing.  One other thing, the action method ShowReport was called from a jquery ajax() method inside the View.  So I was wondering if a full post back occurred when ViewBag.Table was assigned and rendered? (sorry, if the jargon is wrong)

Comment: Ok now I'm lost. This doesn't seem possible. please show your entire view including your JS.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found someone with similiar problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006016/view-not-rendering-mvc-4.  "That's the whole point of AJAX => stay on the same page. If you want to replace the current page don't use any AJAX. Use a normal Html.ActionLink. "  I used an Url.Action in the button onClick and now everything is working fine.  Thanks very much for helping!!!

Comment: There was NOT a full post back. but that's not really your problem. All Razor is rendered once. Ajax calls return values to themselves as JSON. Then you can deserialize them and add them to your DOM with another JQuery operation. If you include your AJAX call, I can help you with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your action method to return JSON content

```
public ActionResult ShowReport(string URL)
    {
        string tableString = ""; 

        [Code to Create table called ReportTable and add rows etc]

        tableString = RenderControlToString(ReportTable );

        //ViewBag.Table= tableString; 

        return this.Content(tableString, "application/json");

    }
```

alter your JQuery to reutilize your return value

```
        success: function(data) {
           $('#divTable').innerHTML(data);
```

and add a div to your view where you want to render the html

```
<div id='divTable'></div>
```

Comment: That was it!! Thanks so much!!  The table is now rendering!

Comment: glad to help. in future, consider using partial views with child action methods and the jquery `.load` method. This is a bit to learn but is a better way to achieve what you want and will give you more flexibility.